Is this video’s description of evolutionary learning correct?
In this video : How AIs, like ChatGPT, Learn, narrator describes a form of machine learning, specifically evolutionary algorithms or evolutionary machine learning.
Stating that, Initially, the builder bot creates student bots almost randomly, and the teacher bot tests them using images of bees and threes. The student bots that survive the tests at first are just lucky.
However, by combining these lucky bots, keeping only the best-performing ones, and making random variations, the process gradually evolves more capable bots. Over time, this leads to a student bot that isn't merely lucky but genuinely begins to distinguish bees from threes.
This iterative process of testing, selecting, and modifying continues until a highly effective bot emerges, even though neither the builder, the teacher, nor humans understand how it works.
How correct this description of evolutionary machine learning actually is?

It is a simplified but ultimately correct description of evolutionary computation.
Technically a large population is not needed.  (1+1)-ES makes a modification and decides if it is better or worse, replacing the one learner if it is.
But broadly the strategies can be seen as gradient-free hill climb optimization and they can be quite effective learners.

Yes, that is how evolutionary algorithms work in general. They are very suitable for hyperparameter optimization, but I don't think they are much used for training the actual models. When the models start having millions or billions of parameters, they converge much faster by using gradient descend algorithms.
Also, the illustrated bot brains resemble more decision trees than neural networks.

What you say about sample efficiency is correct but it’s important to note that GAs work on non-differential problems where gradient descent cannot be used.  Further, decision trees are only one model which can be evolved.  NEAT evolves neural networks and others evolve rule lists, support vectors or almost every other model.

Getting through this paper (1)  I feel that the definition you ask about describes well only a subfield of evolutionary machine learning (EML) and EML is a broader field than that.
The authors of the paper I mentioned frame EML as a bit fuzzy term that is a bag for other subfields. I think that your definition suits Evolutionary Reinforcement Learning.

(1) Telikani, A., Tahmassebi, A., Banzhaf, W., & Gandomi, A. H. (2021). Evolutionary machine learning: A survey. ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR), 54(8), 1-35.

Nothing in the original post describes RL.  It’s a simple classification problem.

@foreverska you might be right, I've been anchored with the 'bot' term. So, coming back to the paper, this case would be classified into a category of Evolutionary Neural Networks and Deep Learning.
